# Swift 5 and can't get this text to show

Tags: swift

I am trying to show some text on the iPhone when I have a process trying to connect to a network and before trying to load the webpage.  In the main ViewController I tried the below but not showing:

```
    @IBOutlet var mWebKit: WKWebView!

let myURL = URL(string: "https:theurl.com")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let request = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    mWebKit.navigationDelegate = self  // Start monitor WebKit output
    
    let testlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mWebKit.frame.size.width, height: mWebKit.frame.size.height))
    testlabel.textAlignment = .center
    testlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 32)
    testlabel.textColor = .red
    testlabel.text = "TESTING"
    mWebKit.addSubview(testlabel)

    CheckVPNConnetionLoop()  
    testlabel.removeFromSuperview()
    mWebKit.load(request) // load page
}
```

So when it takes a while for VPN to connect on the iPhone when the app loads, that CheckVPNConnectionLoop() could run for 6 or more seconds before giving up.  Wanted to have some text or my spinner show before and disappear after.  But I do not see the content when running this on the phone.  On the emulator it works totally different so not going to rely on that.  Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you don't have any constraints

Comment: CheckVPNConnetionLoop almost certainly has asynchronous code that doesn’t finish right away. So, in your current code, you basically add and then remove your label instantaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Thought it was working but then when I put back in the removefromsuperview it wasn't so think jnpdx is right. I basically loop thru in that CheckVPNConnectionLoop and each run if it's not connected it snoozes for 3 seconds and then tries it again.  What is in there is:

```
func checkConnection(completionHandler:@escaping (_ isOnline: Bool?) -> Void){
    let stringurl = "http://" + "<ip>"
    let url = NSURL(string: stringurl)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) {(data, response, error) in
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if (httpResponse?.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String) != nil {
            let isConnected = true
            completionHandler(isConnected)
        }else{
            let isConnected = false
            completionHandler(isConnected)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

That said, the webview isn't called from what I can tell until this process finishes so confused.

Comment: Sorry if I'm putting things in the wrong place, but I ended up creating the label in viewDidLoad and hiding it in didFinish.  Is this wrong?